# function in Redux state

Tags: redux

during my react-redux application development, I have run into a special use case:

Our application take some functions as resources (we dynamically load them, then use them as factory to create instances). Currently I put them in the store state and it works well. However, it seems kind of anti-pattern to put functions in Redux state, which will break the ability to persist and rehydrate the contents of a store.

So I try to move the functions out from the store state: I use a map to save functions and store the corresponding key in the state. The question is, by doing so, my state-to-ui transform no longer retains a pure function. As the functions are dynamicly loaded, content of the functions-map mutates. In different period (e.g. functions loading VS functions loaded), the same store state will result in different UI.

Now I feel that it's not so correct to put the functions in some place out of redux system. I need some advices about where to put these functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing functions in Redux state could be not a good idea exactly because of reasons you mentioned.
You can store in Redux state loading status of your functions. Something like:

```
{
    'loadedFunctions': ['func1', 'func2']
}
```

or something more complex:

```
{
    'functionsStatus': {
        'func1': {
            loaded: false,
            loading: true
        }
    }
}
```

In that case same Redux state should result same UI (if body of your functions doesn't change)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So I should store my functions in some other place and organize them by keys like `func1`, `func2`? That means when I want to use them in the component, I have to get key (such as `func1`) from state and find the real function from the "some other place".

Comment: And then check from the state that this function is loaded, if not - display loader or what you want. In that case you will get more pure relation between redux state and rendered ui.

Comment: But please keep in mind that real applications can be more complex than todo list and maintaining purity everywhere could be not the best decision